# Always fill 100% of parent width

Tags: css

I have a container `DIV` with ***random*** number of children inside.

I always want children to fill 100% width of parent. I tried using do `display:table-cell` and other CSS tricks but all in vain.

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pA3fj/).

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="panel">1
    </div>
    <div class="panel">2
    </div>
    <div class="panel">3
    </div>
    <div class="panel">4
    </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display:table` to the `.wrapper`

http://jsfiddle.net/pA3fj/2/